# How to make a query to SELECT something based on results from another SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: orders, purchase_order and sale_order. Table orders has two columns: foreign key order_id and order_numb. Order_id is id of purchase_order or sale_order, and order_numb is here just to say what order is it about.

order_numb = 1 it is purchase_order
order_numb = 2 it is sale_order

So I need to make select from table orders, and for every row check if it has order_numb = 1 or order_numb = 2, and based on that result make select from purchase_order or sale_order based on theirs id.

I could make it work with two queries but I want to do it in one.

```
ORDER

| order_id | action_numb |
--------------------------
|    51    |      1      |
--------------------------
|    40    |      2      |
--------------------------
|    41    |      2      |
--------------------------
|    52    |      1      |


PURCHASE_ORDER      

| id | other_columns |
----------------------
| 51 |   something   |
----------------------
| 52 |   something   |


SALE_ORDER      

| id | other_columns |
----------------------
| 40 |   something   |
----------------------
| 41 |   something   |
----------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are selecting the same columns from the two tables you can use UNION to accomplish your task.

```
SELECT o.id,<other-columns>
    FROM order o INNER JOIN purchase_order po 
    ON o.id = po.id 
    WHERE o.action_numb = 1 

    UNION

    SELECT o.id,<other-columns>
    FROM order o INNER JOIN sale_order so 
    ON o.id = so.id 
    WHERE o.action_numb = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT o.*
     , CASE
         WHEN so.id is null THEN po.other_columns
         WHEN po.id is null THEN so.other_columns
       END other_columns
  FROM orders o
    LEFT JOIN purchase_order po
      ON    po.id = o.order_id
        AND o.order_numb = 1 
    LEFT JOIN sale_order so
      ON    so.id = o.order_id
        AND o.order_numb = 2
```

Comment: i dont get any results with this